# Different Output When Running Simple Thread Program

Tags: java, multithreading

Why it is giving a different output every time I Run the Program.

```
package threading;
class RunnableDemo implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        go();
    }

    public void go() {
        String name = Thread.currentThread().getName();
        System.out.println(name + "Run method");
    }
}

public class multiThreading {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable myJob = new RunnableDemo();
        Thread job1 = new Thread(myJob);
        Thread job2 = new Thread(myJob);
        job1.setName("Job1");
        job2.setName("Job2");
        job1.start();
        job2.start();
        System.out.println("Main Method");
    }
}
```

Also Job1 Thread is not displaying its setted name.

**output**

Job2Run method
  Main Method
  Thread-1Run method

Comment: Because you had `job1.setName()` twice!!

Comment: Please take some time to ask good questions by indenting your code properly, and respecting the Java naming conventions. Variables start with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @anonymous points out you set one thread twice.

Instead you should do

```
Thread job1 = new Thread(myJob, "Job1");
Thread job2 = new Thread(myJob, "Job2");
```

> Why it is giving a different output every time I Run the Program.

Can you explain what you expected to happen?  You have started two independent threads that can run in any order, by design.

---

> What is not thread safe?

Thread.setName() and Thread.getName() are not thread safe. From the source

```
private char        name[];

public final void setName(String name) {
    checkAccess();
    this.name = name.toCharArray();
}

public final String getName() {
    return String.valueOf(name);
}
```

This means you can set the value in one thread but for the change not to be visible.

NOTE: In this case, it is not an issue because you set the name before the thread is start()ed.  Anything written before a thread is started is guaranteed to be visible.

Comment: We can also make thread safe by making method synchronized . :-)

Comment: @Mubeen true, or maybe setting the name of a thread from another one isn't the best idea.

Answer (score 0):

you did not set the name of Job2 thread :

```
Job1.setName("Job1");
Job1.setName("Job2");
Job1.start();
Job2.start();
```

correct is :

```
Job1.setName("Job1");
Job2.setName("Job2");
Job1.start();
Job2.start();
```